# archiving files by filecreation date

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, filesystems, vb.net-2010

I am trying to get my script to work but seems to be creating the incorrect expected results. I have a folder with 1000s of compressed files in the format "Processedyyyddmmhhmmss.xml.gz". I am trying to move the files to another server location and placing them in dated folders according to the date created. What I find is the date created is incorrect and the files are being placed in folders but scattered by various dates and I cannot figure out a logical way to complete this. Here is what I have:

```
        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(directoryStuff)
        For i As Integer = 0 To files.Count - 1
            counter += 1
            If files(i).EndsWith(".gz") Then
                templist.Add(files(i))
            Else
                Continue For
            End If

            If counter >= 100 Then
                Dim objInfo As New FileInfo(files(0))
                Dim filedate As String = Regex.Replace(objInfo.Name, ".*P_", "")
```

'I changed the above line from 
                   Dim filedate As String = objInfo.CreationTime.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")

'Because I was getting the wrong date

```
                filedate = filedate.Remove(14)
                Dim destDirectory As String = finalDestination & pathName + filedate & "\"
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirectory)
                For j As Integer = 0 To templist.Count - 1
                    Dim ff As String = templist.Item(j)
                    objInfo = New FileInfo(ff)
                    Dim filename As String = objInfo.Name
                    If Not ff.Contains("error") Then
                        File.Move(ff, destDirectory + filename)
                        File.Delete(ff)
                    End If

                Next
                templist.Clear()
            End If
        Next
```

As you can see the logic is flawed. What I do want is to group files according to their created date and place them in the folder dated accordingly. I am not sure how to compare the next created datetime in the folder and separate the files accordingly. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

figured this out.

```
        Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryStuff)

        For i As Integer = 0 To files.Count - 1
        Try

            counter += 1

            Dim objInfo As New FileInfo(files(i))
            Dim filedate As String = Regex.Replace(objInfo.Name, ".*P_", "")
            filedate = filedate.Remove(8)
            Dim destDirectory As String = finalDestination & pathName + "_" + filedate & "\"
            If Not Directory.Exists(destDirectory) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirectory)
            End If
```